# How do I enforce these limits (business limits)?

Tags: c#

I want my site to support different subscription types, free, premium and etc.

So far I made an abstract class that is like this

```
  public abstract class Limits
    {

        public int PostLimit { get; protected set; }


        protected Limits(int postLimit)
        {
            PostLimit = postLimit;
        }

        public bool IsLimitReached(int postCount)
        {
            return postCount > PostLimit 
        }

    }


 public class FreeLimit : Limits
    {
        private const int postLimit = 1;


        public FreeLimit()
            : base(postLimit)
        {
        }

    }
```

So now I did this for all my account types. Now the problem is I don't know how to actually use this class.

For instance I have a service layer call PostService and in this class I have

```
public void CreatePost(Post post)
{
  // do stuff here
}
```

Now in this method I don't know how to check if they reached the limit. I don't know how to check because I am unsure how to find out if I should be using the FreeLimit or PremiumLimit or what account they have.

I am thinking that I first have to figure out their Role and then somehow use that information to create the right class.

I guess I could have something like

```
public void CreatePost(Post post, PlanType planType)
{
   Limits limit;
   switch(planType)
   {
      case planType.Free:
         limit = new FreeLmit()
        break;
   }

    if(limit.IsLimitReached())
    {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

I don't like this way as now for every method that needs to check a limit will have to do this. I will have a few methods that require this check in my service layer.

So I was thinking of putting it in my constructor but I don't know if it is good to have a switch statement in a constructor.

Comment: you mean there are more methods than CreatePost that need to check the Post post, PlanType planType?

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne - Well this was just an example I made up(I dont' really have a post limit). PlanType would just be a enum that would hold the plan they currently are on.

Comment: I do not agree with using Limits as an abstract class and inheriting from it.  If your subclasses would vary by a number, why subclass them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an interface `ILimit`

```
interface ILimit
{
    int PostLimit { get; protected set; }
    bool IsLimitReached(int postCount);
}
```

Now you can have several other classes (Free, Premium, Super) that implement this interface. In your service method `CreatePost` you can just pass any instance of a class that implements the interface and use it - there's no need to distinguish them anymore since they all support the same interface.

```
public void CreatePost(Post post, ILimit limit)
{
    if(limit.IsLimitReached())
    {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this but the thing I don't like about this is that I need to repeat myself every single time. I mean IsLimitReached is the same method it just does a if statement. But now I am writing this same method 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `Limit` property is tied to what entity? I suppose it's tied to the Blog (or maybe a Forum) and it is persisted on a DB or something else.

If so, you can do something like this:

```
public void CreatePost(Post post)
{
    if(post.Blog.IsLimitReached())
    {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

The `Blog.IsPostLimitReached()` should call `this.Limit.IsLimitReached` from itself.

I hope you can understand what I said :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have different types of user, you can tie their accounts (once they've logged in) to different `RoleTypes`.  Then you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("RoleName")` to see if they are in a specific role, and use that as your basis for showing/hiding functionality.

Comment: Just to be clear, you may need to implement a class based on RoleProvider to do this, you can then tie User Accounts (using .NET's built-in Membership stuff) to different roles.  This will obviously only work if you require your users to be logged in.